# cmi.core.lesson_location does not return the same string I stored in it?

Tags: javascript, string, scorm, scorm1.2

I am currently developing a wrapper around a existing LMS to make it SCORM complaint. For this purpose I am using cmi.core.lesson_location to store some course related data. I know that cmi.core.lesson_location stores only 255 characters. But When I am settind it to a string which has more  than 200 characters it returns me a truncated string.

I cant identify any pattern any one expeirenced similar kind of issues? Some times it returns a truncated string ending with %3 or something like that. Is there any encoding issues while using cmi.core.lesson_location? If so can anyone post them

Thank you
Swaroop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string contains non-alphanumeric characters and it gets URLEncoded at some point, each non-alphanumeric character actually becomes 3 characters and your string gets truncated.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out later on

Answer (score 0):

You can use cmi.suspend_data instead of cmi.core.lession_location. The cmi.suspend_data can store more data.

Comment: Yeah I no that I am using cmi.suspend_data too. I have to provide capability to store in both the fields. So that I can store 4351 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Cmi.suspend_data should store 4096 bytes. The LMS could store more... Or less bytes. You should test it.